# File size grows greatly after using awk

Tags: awk

I want to add row number for a file, then I do like this,

```
awk '{print $0 "\x03" NR > "/opt/data2/gds_test/test_partly.txt"}' /opt/data2/gds_test/test_partly.txt
```

I put this line of command in a shell script file, and run it for some time, it still does not finish, so I end it by force, but I find the source file size has changed from 1.7G to 242G,

What happened? I am a little confused,

I had ever use a small file to test in command line, this awk command seems ok,

Comment: IMHO you are using same input file and outputfile without using inplace option so that could be the reason for file's size. It's not recommended to save output into input file itself without inplace option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading from the front of a file at the same time as you're writing onto the end of it. Try this instead:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk '{print $0 "\x03" NR}' '/opt/data2/gds_test/test_partly.txt' > "$tmp" &&
mv "$tmp" '/opt/data2/gds_test/test_partly.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, i change to redirect the result to a tmp file, and then delete the original file and rename the tmp file, it is ok,

and i just also get to know that gawk -I inplace can be used,